# how to unload openssl engine C++

Tags: c++, openssl

I coppied gost.dll engine file to a temporary folder and then loaded it like this

```
    if (ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(engine_gost, "SO_PATH", szPathToGostDLL.mbc_str(), 0))
    {
        if (ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(engine_gost, "ID", szEngineName.mbc_str(), 0))
        {
            if (ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(engine_gost, "LOAD", NULL, 0))
                goto ok;
        }
    }
```

then I do some work and unload it like this

```
ENGINE_finish(engine_gost);
ENGINE_free(engine_gost);

ERR_remove_state(0);
ERR_free_strings();

ENGINE_cleanup();
EVP_cleanup();

CONF_modules_finish();
CONF_modules_free();
CONF_modules_unload(true);

CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
```

The problem is I cannot remove file gost.dll
How to proppely UnLoad the engine?